# How to fill content of div with image

Tags: css

I am creating a social site and people can upload images. When they upload those image it is inside of a div. How do I fill the whole div up so i don't see white spaces on the sides ?

This is how it looks now:

[First Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOav1.png)

[Second e.g](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abFsl.png)

My code:

```
.postedImageDiv {
max-width: 500px;
overflow: hidden;
max-height: 400px;
border-radius: 10px;
border: 1px solid gray;
background: #fff;
margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.profilePostedImage img {

max-height: 450px;
max-width: 450px;
display: block;
margin: 5px auto;
}

.postedImage img {

align-self: center;
object-fit: contain;
max-height: 600px;
max-width: 600px;
display: block;
margin: 5px auto;
border-radius: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: What if you try `object-fit: cover` instead of `object-fit: contain`?

Comment: @agrm doesn't help either

Comment: I see now you are trying to remove the white space. Remove the margin you have added to `.postedImage img` or `.profilePostedImage img` (whichever holds the image)

Comment: @agrm That didn't help either

Comment: Try setting the child div's width height to 100% since you declare the max width and height to it's parent

Comment: If you get no further, I suggest putting up a working sample and some details of what you tried so far, as this will make debugging and testing a lot easier :o)

Answer (score 0):

You might try these:

```
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: block;
```

```css
.outside {
  max-width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 400px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.img-inside{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- vertical image example -->
<div class="outside">
  <img class="img-inside" src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/86c3481516dce247943ac2978b4f48d16a3ac265/0_170_5120_3074/master/5120.jpg?width=1200&height=1200&quality=85&auto=format&fit=crop&s=637dc5731d52754675ef36344a6af3c8">
</div>
<!-- landscape image example -->
<div class="outside">
  <img class="img-inside" src="https://www.straight.com/files/v3/styles/gs_standard/public/images/15/03/shutterstock_grizzlybear_0.jpg?itok=vz6hpl50">
</div>
```

Comment: For which class ?

Comment: the class that setup the image size and properties. with your css only, i cant figure out which class is your image belongs to

Comment: That didn't help

Comment: I'm not sure, but this might helps: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp